# How to configure Hot Reloading in Vue/Webpack to work on any test domain

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3, hot-reload

I create a backend project in a scripting language and a frontend using Vue-CLI. The project is tested in the domain `example.localhost`. In the test environment I run the Vue-CLI development version (`localhost:8080`) and use it on the project page `example.localhost:80`. This part works. "Hot Reloading" doesn't work.

> On the Vue-CLI, Webpack, and SockJS project repositories, I saw issue threads about the failure of this module due to changes in SockJS, but a workaround was added that until the SockJS case is resolved.

I found a working configuration in my case, but this configuration is very dependent on the test domain name, which is what I would like to avoid. I would like it to work on other test domains and it doesn't work in its current form.

In previous attempts I even had a situation with CORS, but in preparing this example I was not able to get this state again. I do not accept the solution with `disableHostCheck: true`. The thing is, it must work without compromising security.

---

./**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  dev:
    image: gander/dev:7.3
    volumes:
      - ./public/index.html:/www/example.localhost/public/index.html
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

./public/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">Vue App</div>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

./**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "sandbox-vue-dev",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.4.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

---

./vue/**vue.config.js**, Hot Reloading not working:

```js
module.exports = {
    outputDir: '../public/js/',
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filenameHashing: false,
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    chainWebpack(config) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks(false);
        config.output.filename('[name].js');
        ['html', 'preload', 'prefetch'].forEach(plugin => {
            config.plugins.delete(plugin);
        });
    }
};
```

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 8080
    },
    outputDir: '../public/js/',
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filenameHashing: false,
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    chainWebpack(config) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks(false);
        config.output.filename('[name].js');
        ['html', 'preload', 'prefetch'].forEach(plugin => {
            config.plugins.delete(plugin);
        });
    }
};
```

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '.localhost'
        }
    },
    outputDir: '../public/js/',
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filenameHashing: false,
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    chainWebpack(config) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks(false);
        config.output.filename('[name].js');
        ['html', 'preload', 'prefetch'].forEach(plugin => {
            config.plugins.delete(plugin);
        });
    }
};
```

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        host: 'localhost'
    },
    outputDir: '../public/js/',
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filenameHashing: false,
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    chainWebpack(config) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks(false);
        config.output.filename('[name].js');
        ['html', 'preload', 'prefetch'].forEach(plugin => {
            config.plugins.delete(plugin);
        });
    }
};
```

./vue/**vue.config.js**, Hot Reloading working, but *hardcode* domain:

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        host: 'example.localhost'
    },
    outputDir: '../public/js/',
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filenameHashing: false,
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    chainWebpack(config) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks(false);
        config.output.filename('[name].js');
        ['html', 'preload', 'prefetch'].forEach(plugin => {
            config.plugins.delete(plugin);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem today (January 11, 2023) when trying to integrate Django + VueJS through this tutorial: https://www.webucator.com/article/connecting-django-and-vue/.

In order to solve it, I just had to add the `devServer.headers` section to `vue.config.js`, as explained in https://www.fabiofranchino.com/log/how-to-enable-cors-on-vue-cli-serve/:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer: {
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
    }
  }
}
```

It worked perfectly for me.